# Fetching current loggedin user using spring security

Tags: authentication, spring-security, extjs4

I have a problem in getting the logged in user in my spring-extjs application.I am using spring security 2.0.4.Here are the details of what i have tried.

Controller class:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/StaffingApplication/index.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printUser(ModelMap model) {
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username    
  System.out.println(name);
  model.addAttribute("username", name);
  return "index.jsp";
}
```

login.js file

```js
var login = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelWidth:80,
    url:'j_spring_security_check',
    frame:true,
    title:'Please Login',
    defaultType:'textfield',
    width:300,
    height:130,
    monitorValid:true,
    // Specific attributes for the text fields for username / password.
    // The "name" attribute defines the name of variables sent to the server.

    items:[{
        fieldLabel:'Username',
        name:'j_username',
        allowBlank:false
    },{
        fieldLabel:'Password',
        name:'j_password',
        inputType:'password',
        allowBlank:false
    }],

    // All the magic happens after the user clicks the button
    buttons:[{
        text:'Login',
        formBind: true,
        // Function that fires when user clicks the button
        handler:function(){
        login.getForm().submit({

            method:'POST', 

            // Functions that fire (success or failure) when the server responds.
            // The server would actually respond with valid JSON,
            // something like: response.write "{ success: true}" or

            // response.write "{ success: false, errors: { reason: 'Login failed. Try again.' }}"
            // depending on the logic contained within your server script.
            // If a success occurs, the user is notified with an alert messagebox,

            // and when they click "OK", they are redirected to whatever page
            // you define as redirect. 

            success:function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Login Successful!', function(btn, text){
                if (btn == 'ok'){
                      window.location = 'index.action';
                }
            });

        },

        // Failure function, see comment above re: success and failure.
        // You can see here, if login fails, it throws a messagebox
        // at the user telling him / her as much.  


        failure:function(form, action){
            if(action.failureType == 'server'){
                obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);

                Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed!', obj.errors.reason);
            }else{
                Ext.Msg.alert('Warning!', 'Authentication server is unreachable : ' + action.response.responseText);
                //window.location='loginFailure.html'+action.response.responseText; 
            }
            login.getForm().reset();
        } 

        });
    }
    }]
});
```

On my jsp page I access it like this.

```html
<div id="header" class="header">Options Staffing Application
    <div style="" id="user-status">
        <a href='<c:url value="j_spring_security_logout"/>'>Logout</a>
        <h3>Username : ${username}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I just get a blank in place of username.
When I try to print it in the controller I get the value printed,but doesn't seem to be displayed on the jsp page.Went throgh other threads but did not help.Any help would be appreciated

Thanks for the time
Sachin

Comment: are you sure that you are going to the jsp right after the controller class? because this seems like the request is lost by the moment you reach the jsp

Comment: Yes I am not going to jsp, but then I am not able to debug it.Checked the logs but not able to track the mistake. Can you correct where I am going wrong.                                                               Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put the username into an object model because you can access it from a jsp just like the way you do in the controller class:

```html
<h3>Username <%=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName(); =></h3>
```

Or even better:

```html
<h3>Username <sec:authentication property="name" /></h3>
```

But i'm not sure if you can use that taglib in Spring Security 2

Comment: Thanks for the comment it helped.I got the answer by using ModelAndView i.e I used `@RequestMapping(value="/index.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView main(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,ModelMap model) throws Exception{
     Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username    
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
  System.out.println(name);
     return new ModelAndView("index");
    }` but can you explain how both differ in implementation?

Comment: Again, you don't need to store the username as a model attribute because you can access it wherever you are via SecurityContextHolder. I mean, you are working in a job that Spring Security has already done for you.

Comment: Got your point,the framework has implemented it and we just have to use it.Thank you for the help.I have posted another problem I have come across(more of a logical one) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545369/issue-with-mapping-email-ids-to-specific-users     Please check and help if possible